# Tracing C# DLL function calls

Tags: c#, dll, reflector

[Legacy Application (Belongs to Vendor)] -> [DLL (Obfuscated)] -> [New Subsystem (replaced)]

I have been given a DLL, which is obfuscated (except the name of the function which are public).

I can't decompile it, and also do not have any reference manual on how to invoke those calls.

Is there a way for me to inject some code so that I know the sequence how it is been called?

The DLL is quite complicated, it is not possible for me to write a proxy between this DLL and my function.

I need to ensure that I am able to replace the DLL, and point it to the new subsystem without causing any hiccup to the legacy application which is provided by other vendor.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ILSpy](https://ilspy.net/). Open up the DLL, choose any method to analyse and select [image] to analyse the method. A new window will open up, which shows you three categories (Uses, Used By and Overridden By). You can navigate through the hierarchy. 
[image: analyzer window ilspy]

If there are any free tools which can show the trace at runtime... I don't know. But I am currently using ANTS Performance Profiler which shows the trace (including performance details).

And finally there is this article on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15410/Creating-a-Custom-NET-Profiler
It shows how to build a "Custom .NET Profiler" and saves the trace in a textfile:

```
System.IO.StringWriter.Write, id=70671928, call count = 622
  System.Text.StringBuilder.Append, id=21629200, call count = 635
    System.IntPtr.op_Inequality, id=21665400, call count = 717
    System.String.AppendInPlace, id=9670768, call count = 635
System.Configuration.XmlUtilWriter.AppendAttributeValue, id=73427152, call count = 14
  System.Xml.XmlTextReader.get_QuoteChar, id=70046432, call count = 14
    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_QuoteChar, id=70049120, call count = 14
```